# How to use typename in c++?

Tags: c++, typename

I have read the book named C++ primer and I don't understand the following code:

```
typedef typename std::vector<int>::size_type size_type;
```

Could you help me explain the use of `typename` here?

Comment: its called dependent type, the typename keyword is a grammar disambiguator to differentiate from function declaration. there are already many questions about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords?lq=1

Comment: Note that it is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: To be clear: you do **not** need `typename` here. You *would* need it in `template <class T> struct Foo { typedef typename std::vector<T>::size_type size_type; };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read `typedef typename std::vector::size_type size_type` like this:

`typedef` `typename std::vector::size_type` `size_type`, just like `typedef __int64 INT64`.

Why we need `typename` beforce `std::vector::size_type`? It just tells the compiler that `std::vector::size_type` is a type not a normal class member. It's used for disambiguation.

But I think maybe some compiler can auto detect `std::vector::size_type` is a type.

So, `typedef` just creates an alias for an existing type, and `typename` tells the compile that `std::vector::size_type` is a type not a normal class member.